# Is the mitzvah to honor the bechor d'oraisa or d'raban?

Tags: family-members, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, kavod, bechor-firstborn

I see in the answer to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83216/is-there-a-mitzvah-to-honor-the-bechor) question that the mitzvah to honor one's mother and father includes an obligation to honor one's oldest brother. This idea is originally referenced in Ketubot 103a. Is this commandment to honor the older brother d'oraisa or d'raban?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1453/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source for this is *derasha* in the Talmud (Ketubot 103a):

> כבד את אביך ואת אמך את אביך זו אשת אביך ואת אמך זו בעל אמך וי"ו יתירה לרבות את אחיך הגדול
>
> Honor your father [et avikha] and your mother [ve’et immekha]. The preposition et in the phrase: Your father; this teaches that you must honor your father’s wife. Similarly, the preposition et in the phrase: And your mother; this teaches that you must honor your mother’s husband. And the extra letter vav, which is appended as a prefix in the phrase “ve’et immekha” is included in order to add your older brother to those who must be honored.

The Meiri writes (Ketubot there) that it is rabbinic and the the *derasha* is a mere *asmakhta*:

> חייב אדם לכבד אשת האב וכן בעל האם ודבר זה מצוה מדברי סופרים וסמכוה מן המקרא כבד את אביך לרבות אשת אביך ואת אמך לרבות בעל אמך ולא סוף דבר אשת אב או בעל אם בחיי האם אלא אף לאחר מיתה וכן חייב אדם לכבד אחיו הגדול והוא שאמרו וא"ו יתירה לרבות אחיך הגדול ואף על פי שהזכירו בסוגיא זו שכבוד אשת אב דאוריתא וכמו שהקשו אשת אב דאוריתא לא אמרוה אלא דרך סמך ובהרבה מקומות מצינו כיוצא בזה כמו במסכת תענית כ"ח ב' אמרו הלל דראש חדש לאו דאוריתא כלומר הא של מועדות דאוריתא ובמועד קטן י"א ב' אמרו חולו של מועד דאסירא ביה מלאכה מדאוריתא וכן בהרבה מקומות

Rambam codifies the Talmud's ruling in Hilkhot Mamrim (6:17):

> ומדברי סופרים, שיהיה אדם חייב בכבוד אחיו הגדול ככבוד אביו
>
> By rabbinic teaching one is obligated to honour his elder brother, as he honours his father.

He employs his notoriously ambiguous term "divrei soferim" to describe the nature of this commandment.

Unsurprisingly, many debate whether he agrees with Meiri that it is rabbinic, or thinks that it is as authoritative as a full fledged derasha (which in Rambam's scheme still constitutes a discrete; not d'orayta category). Arokh HaShulhan (YD 240:43) opines that according to Rambam it is rabbinic. See Minhat Hinnukh (33) who raises the question, and Shut Divrei Yatsiv (YD 128) who discusses the question as well.

Comment: @Ze'ev If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying what additional information you are looking for.