# Is there a mitzvah to honor the bechor?

Tags: family-members, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, kavod, bechor-firstborn

I have heard that the mitzvah to honor ones parents includes a commandment to honor one's oldest brother. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Talmud ([Ketubot 103a](http://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.103a.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) states:

> כבד את אביך ואת אמך את אביך זו אשת אביך ואת אמך זו בעל אמך וי"ו יתירה לרבות את אחיך הגדול
>
> Honor your father [et avikha] and your mother [ve’et immekha]. The preposition et in the phrase: Your father; this teaches that you must honor your father’s wife. Similarly, the preposition et in the phrase: And your mother; this teaches that you must honor your mother’s husband. And the extra letter vav, which is appended as a prefix in the phrase “ve’et immekha” is included in order to add your older brother to those who must be honored.

Rambam codifies this in Hilkhot Mamrim ([6:17](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e306.htm#17)):

> ומדברי סופרים, שיהיה אדם חייב בכבוד אחיו הגדול ככבוד אביו
>
> By rabbinic teaching one is obligated to honour his elder brother, as he honours his father.

This is in turn quoted by the Shulhan Arukh ([YD 240:22](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.240.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

It should be noted that there is a dispute whether this refers exclusively to the oldest brother, or to any older brother. See Gilyon Maharsha to Shulhan Arukh (YD 240:22) who cites the the view that it refers only to the oldest brother, while others such as the Arizal cited by Hida in Pnei David (V'zot Haberakha: 13) opine that it applies to any older brother.

Comment: this is only when the patents ate alive